# How to fix ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, ibtool

I have never encountered this problem before. The application used to run perfectly but now it always says this error. I have tried cleaning and rebooting. I have tried resetting IOS Simulator. I have tried deleting derived data.

This is what it says:

```
CompileStoryboard YoungstersTennisApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard
cd /Users/DJ/Desktop/YoungstersTennisApp
setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/DJ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YoungstersTennisApp-ftehnuqeslbyekfiszajlixujbqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YoungstersTennisApp.app/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboardc /Users/DJ/Desktop/YoungstersTennisApp/YoungstersTennisApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard
```

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Any help for this would be great. I also have quite a large storyboard. Does that matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is xcode getting quit while clicking the storyboard file?

Comment: no it isn't @Ganapathy

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you happen to solve whatever your issue was, @user2947604?

Comment: Editor -> Resolve Auto Layouts Issues -> Add Missing Constraints in Container (Update Constraints in Container)

Comment: I had this issue with my Launch Screen.xib. I just quit Xcode and cleaned the code and it started working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting ibtool failed with exit code 255?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue with XCode 6 and iOS 8.

Just a XIB was giving me errors when I tried to compile.

I've tried to clean the project and the problem persisted.

Then I've opened the view that was giving me problems, I've saved again (WITHOUT CHANGING ANYTHING AT ALL) and... voila! My app up and running. XCode is satanic :)

Comment: Thanks - also had this problem on Xcode 6 beta 7 / iOS8 - this solved it

Comment: I am even not able to open that file. XCode crashes instantly.

Answer (score 7):

I also had this issue, after upgrade xCode to version 7.0 beta 6.

My way as below:

1. Delete the "DerivedData" folder
2. Rebuild the project (it will create new "DerivedData" folder )

Hope it will help to someone...

Comment: where is that folder locateD?

Comment: Please reference the Jayprakash Dubey ->    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279141/how-can-i-safely-delete-in-my-library-developer-xcode-deriveddata-directory

Comment: Worked for me, +1

Comment: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ is the folder path

Answer (score 5):

Cleaning ang re-building project solved the problem for me (xcode 5)

```
Shift - cmd - K 
cmd - K
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with this issue by having a `UITableView` with `static cells` that wasn't in a `UITableViewController`, but instead had a subclass of a `UIViewController`. Changing my subclass to instead inherit from `UITableViewController` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning project, cleaning build folder and restarting xcode solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, after a big merge, and when i click on the .xib the xCode getting quit.
Maybe you left some of the old Code, check the id of the view, also the id with problem is shown in the detail screen of the error message when xcode Quit so:

- Open the .xib with the text editor
- Check that the id of an element should appears twice; in the "subviews" group and in "connections"  group if you connected as a property
- remove the the code that you don't need and save the file

Hope it will help, Constantin

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after with xcode 8.2 after deleting one of my view controllers. to fix it I just cleaned my build folder and it worked again

to clean build folder:

### -> menu -> product (while pressing option) -> Clean build folder

or

### option + shift + command + K

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 9 getting error while building for archive: What worked for me was to clean my project, and then build for a simulator device, and then try to build for archive again.  Xcode is rather temperamental sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in xcode 9 by unchecking and checking "Use Trait Variations" in storyboard File inspector.

[image]

xcode

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error I could not find exact solution for that. After some time I realised my problem.
My project files are
AppDelegate.h

AppDelegate.m

LoginViewcontroller.h

LoginViewXontroller.m

LoginViewController.xib

I have added one new storyboard file. And I changed label and button connections from nib(.xib) file to storyboard file.  After that I got this error.

I removed connections from storyboard and added connections to .xib file again. clean and build that's it my problem is solved. I hope it will helpful to someone..