# Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I am getting following warning on OS X 10.9 console at the time of nib load(`NSWindowController`).

```
Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
```

I am using Xcode 6 and OS X 10.10 to compile my code. Most probably this warning is coming because of [NSColor exposes new system colors in 10.10 for static text and related elements: labelColor, secondaryLabelColor, tertiaryLabelColor, and quaternaryLabelColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/).

How to fix this warning?

Comment: Are this warning showing in the log when you execute the app under 10.9 or is it when you open the project in Xcode in a 10.9 environment?

Comment: When i am executing on 10.9

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your textfield's color in your xib file from:

```
<color key="textColor" name="labelColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
```

to:

```
<color key="textColor" name="textColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
```

Since "labelColor" is not a formal color name in OSX 10.9.

Comment: This is a great workaround but I encourage you all to file a radar for this. Xcode seems to ignore the minimum target and therefore breaks the XIB. We shouldn't need a preflight script to edit out an obvious format error.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is there to inform you the color is not available in 10.9 (or below). You could simply check the OS version (using AppKit constant `NSAppKitVersionNumber`) and handle the color properly according to the version.

Good reading:  [Apple Developer Guide on SDK Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: This warning is coming when i am loading xib and i can not access any property/object of xib before loading.