# Incompatibility 10.10 to 10.8

Tags: macos, compatibility, xcode7

I have an app developped under Xcode7 in 10.10
I changed the deployment target system to 10.8 because of the IT situation of another school. 
The 10.8 app runs fine under 10.10, but on an 10.8 machine, I only see a window grayed out in the face of the MainMenu.xib included the menus, but inactive. Its reaction are as in IB. The previous login windows called at startup are not shown. 
In the console I only see a warning about 'Invalid color System labelColor'.

Explanation:
I reduced my project to the Start nib window and the MainMenu.xib. I looked for labelColor in every single nib and xib file with BBedit. 
When I compile, I look in the content of the compiled app and can find a MainMenu.nib (not xib) with a single String Item labelColor.
Runnig the app in 10.10 is fine, but in 10.9 the warning appears.

Explanation 2:
Problem fixed: The labelColor is inserted in 10.10/Xcode7 with an NSBox inserted in IB. Obviously this was changed when I transfered the rather old project to Xcode7. I don't know if this is changeble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507727/invalid-color-system-labelcolor-warning-given-only-once)

Comment: Did not solve my Problem. See explanation above.