# Run custom shell script 'Copy Pods Resources' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shell

I have recently been encountering with a Xcode build issue. 
The error message :

```
PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-ctiynisxuxnyspgkmjrwbzdlcppc/Build/Intermediates/XXXX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXXX.build/Script-CD61667E1C3E477BBD8B461C.sh
    cd "/Users/XXX/XXXXX/03_Project/XXXX-ios"
    /bin/sh -c /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-ctiynisxuxnyspgkmjrwbzdlcppc/Build/Intermediates/XXXX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXXX.build/Script-CD61667E1C3E477BBD8B461C.sh

ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-ctiynisxuxnyspgkmjrwbzdlcppc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXXX.app/PTEAdjustLevelsCell.nib /Users/XXX/XXXXX/03_Project/XXXX-ios/Pods/LumberjackConsole/Source/Adjust Levels/PTEAdjustLevelsCell.xib --sdk /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/b03931/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-ctiynisxuxnyspgkmjrwbzdlcppc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/detox.app/PTEDashboard.nib /Users/XXX/XXXXX/03_Project/XXXX-ios/Pods/LumberjackConsole/Source/PTEDashboard.xib --sdk /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255
```

I guess there is something wrong with the 2 files : PTEAdjustLevelsCell.xib and PTEDashboard.xib but have no idea about how to figure out the wrong point exactly. Can anybody tell me the way how to find the problem? Any hint is welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think below is the case which also cause this error, there might be other configuration changes as well but you can try this thing once.

> - Project's Target
> - Build Phases check for entries **Check Pods Manifest.lock** and **Copy Pods Resources**.
> - Check option **Run script only when installing** if it has not selected.

Clean build & run again.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Now the question is, why didn't CocoaPod check those options automatically during `pod install`??

Comment: Thanks, same question :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this cause by the sdk version and xib compiler tool, but xcode could not fix it, you should do something for fix the ibtool. Solutions in this article:[ibtool fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255)

Comment: Hi @Feng Lin, I've read the link you replied some hours before I ask this question. But it didn't help me. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: Hi @Feng Lin , I eventually recognized that the problem is my develop env . I used Xcode 5.0 and it does not support iOS7 SDK. After updating it to Xcode 6.1.1, the error disappeared. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. In the project directory, execute this command:

```
pod update
```

This solved my problem.