# ibtool failed with exit code 1 xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

Showing Recent Messages
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 1. The tool may have crashed. Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with the above output and attach any crash logs for ibtool, ibtoold, Xcode, and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool created around the time of this failure. These logs can be found in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports or /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

Comment: I think This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255) may help you to rectify it.

Comment: Nothing in that referenced link worked for me. Now have this problem with Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)

Answer (score 1):

- Close your project and quit Xcode.
- Reopen Xcode, Go to Xcode -> Perferences -> Location -> Click on Dervied Data arrow (opens a new window)
- Select and delete all the folders in Derived Data Folder.
- Clean your project and Build it.
- Run your project.