# interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error - exit 255 - What this error means?

Tags: ios, xcode9

I'm having this error and it came from nowhere. The compiler was working well until last week. My compiler is taking a lot of time to compile the code and almost all of the times are returning me this error.
I've been having a lot of trouble after the iOS 11 was release.
Do you know what it means?

[image]

I have Xcode9 and I'm asking if it's a problem with the new version or something like else. Also I don't know how to fix this, since I was searching for this answer this last 5 days with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting ibtool failed with exit code 255?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255)

Comment: Did you merge storyboards with other commits?

Comment: Nope. I'm just commit my code twice in the week. After the iOS 11 update I've been having lots of warnings, mainly about constraints. After this last update I got this error and it's taking an eternity to compile the code. =/ I really don't know what to do now. I've been searching for this errors for days and without success.

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning the project and derived data, try to uncheck the following option:

```
Xcode->Preferences->General->Issues->"Show live issues"
```

Comment: No success. Stil not building! :(